# How can I change figure edges of a figure created with imshow?

Tags: matlab, figure, imshow, edges

I'm using `imshow` to create this binary image. When it shows the figure I see a grey background and no edges in the figure. If I save the plot in as `.png`, I see the background as white and I can't see any edges on the figure. How can I add edges to this plot?

Image as shown by `imshow`:

[image: image showed by imshow command]

Image as saved to PNG:

[image: image saved in a .png format]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] the question to contain the code you used, this makes it easier for us to help you. This piece of code is called a [mcve], make sure it's minimal and complete, i.e. don't give unnecessary variables, and give some input data (can be randomly generated) to enable us to run this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, saved figures have a white background. Ensure that the colors of the saved figure match the colors on the display by setting the `InvertHardcopy` property of the figure to `'off'`.

Example:

```
A = rand(300, 300) > 0.1;

f = figure();
  f.InvertHardcopy = 'off';
  imshow(A);
  title('Binary Image threshold 0.9');
  saveas(f, 'test.png');
```

gives:

[image]

Alternatively, it is possible to set the visibility of the axes in the `imshow` and make the ticks empty:

```
A = rand(300, 300) > 0.1;

f = figure();
  iptsetpref('ImshowAxesVisible', 'on');
  imshow(A);
  xticks({});
  yticks({});
  title('Binary Image threshold 0.9');
  saveas(f, 'test.png');
```

that gives:

[image]

Source: [Matlab Documentation](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/save-figure-preserving-background-color.html)